# Portable Class Library vs Platform-Specific Releases

Tags: .net, multiplatform, portable-class-library

With the introduction of the [Portable Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx), developers can release a single library which is compatible across multiple platforms.  The down-side to this is that the PCL must reduce itself to the lowest common set of classes which are compatible across ALL the specified platforms.

If you want to play to the strengths and functionality of specific platforms, (or if you want access to classes which only exist in certain platforms), I assume you have to do one of the following:

1. Release a "base" set of classes as a Portable Class Library, with accompanying Platform-Specific libraries which build on it.

   - One example could be an MVVM library: release common base classes as a single Portable Class Library - named "MyCustomMvvm.dll" - and release some additional platform functionality in the form of "MyCustomMvvm.Extras.WPF.dll" and "MyCustomMvvm.Extras.WP7.dll," etc... OR:
2. Keep a separate project for each platform, using "linked" source files and #if statements to conditionally compile platform-specific functionality.

   - For this example all the libraries would have the same filename ("MyCustomMvvm.dll"), but would have a separate copy for each platform, built using a platform-specific project within your solution.

My question is: are those the only two options?  Is there a clearly "better" option?

Comment: I think the portable class library is the best and cleanest way to do this. But yes, of course this only works for generic code that doesn't use platform-specific features.

Comment: That would pretty much depend on your project. Do you have a lot of platform specific features? Is the lowest set of classes a big restriction in your use case? What if you want to later target another non listed platform, like monodroid/monotouch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rxteam/archive/2012/03/12/reactive-extensions-v2-0-beta-available-now.aspx specifcally the section "Towards a Portable Library world".  Rx targets a lot of different runtimes so it's a good example use case.  They have generally done what you suggest as option 1 and use NuGet to manage a lot of the distribution.

NuGet 2.1 is making changes to help in this endeavor: http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/391121

Your second suggestion is how MVVM light does it per http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsplaisted/archive/2012/08/27/how-to-make-portable-class-libraries-work-for-you.aspx except there's no reason to name all the assemblies the same.

i'm not sure if there are reliable or useful alternatives.

Comment: I noticed one admission in the article: "Rx for Portable Library includes .NET Framework 4.5 and .NET for Metro style applications."  It seems the PCL required them to drop support for some platforms, at least temporarily.

Comment: that's because the PCL doesn't include IObservable<T> for SL4,SL5,& Win Phone 7.x see  https://skydrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=8A7FB4A4B32FB2C9!180&app=Excel   linked from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsplaisted/archive/2012/08/27/how-to-make-portable-class-libraries-work-for-you.aspx   surprisingly the PCL has different libraries on different platforms which i believe is a bit counter intuitive.

Comment: Can by clarify by what you mean "PCL has different libraries on different platforms"?

Comment: As per the Daniel Plaisted article (which turned out to be the winning link in this case), It looks like my "#2 option" is how MVVM Light used to do it, and now they're hoping to move towards a more PCL-friendly implementation.  It appears the answer to migrating to the PCL is to "get better at abstraction."

Comment: @DavidKean what i mean is different targets platforms have different classes available to them. When you create a PCL library you decide what targets you want to include and what's available to you is the least common denominator across all target platforms.  My intuition would be that the PCL would be the same across all platforms.  Check that link for a giant spreadsheet of all the classes and their availability in each target.

Comment: Chris, we could have done it like that, but the problem then is that you become limited by Xbox. ie No networking, no serialization, no ViewModel types. Which reduces the value of it. Long term, we'll just make sure things are everywhere, but short term we have to have different combinations.

Comment: @DavidKean no doubt it makes total sense the way it was developed, it just wasn't my first guess as to what portable class library was.  I thought it was a library based on a more restricted BCL.  But this is way better.